# Time Series Plot showing incorrect leading zeros

Tags: r, plot, time-series

I'm running a time series on monthly data with no missing values. Regardless of what year I set "start=c", I get several months/years of zero values.

Starting at 2016:

```
    date <- as.Date(as.yearmon(format(Vended$Year_Month),"%m_%Y"))
    timeseries <- ts(Vended$OTIF, start = c(2016), end=c(2018), 
    frequency=12)
    plot.ts(timeseries)
```

No Start date:

```
    date <- as.Date(as.yearmon(format(VendedTS$YearMonth),"%m_%Y"))
    timeseries2 <- ts(VendedTS$OTIF,end=c(2018), frequency=12)
    plot.ts(timeseries2)
```

2016 as start date:

[image]

No start date:

[image]

The following is a dput (I hope) of the rows  25-35 of my data.

```
> small<- (VendedTS[25:35,])
> dput(small)
structure(list(YearMonth = c("OCT 2007", "NOV 2007", "DEC 2007", 
"JAN 2008", "FEB 2008", "MAR 2008", "APR 2008", "MAY 2008", "JUN 2008", 
"JUL 2008", "AUG 2008"), TR_CountofLines = c(40004, 33026, 38336, 
21142, 22547, 27088, 40489, 47710, 41008, 36740, 29112), TR_Value_LineItems = c(3454320.63, 
3617021.03, 4055182.81, 2471699.18, 2128728.17, 2250244.34, 3081359.17, 
3906115.74, 2932821.35, 2679508.65, 2195936.78), OTIF = c(0.28037196280372, 
0.14748985647672, 0.04249269616027, 0.15717529089017, 0.24876923759258, 
0.49556999409333, 0.51194151497938, 0.12167260532383, 0.30598907530238, 
0.22852476864453, 0.52442291838417)), row.names = c(NA, -11L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame")
```

EDIT: I do expect to see 0 values for 2005-2007, but none after that.

Thanks in advance!
Annie

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Please include a sample of your data with `dput`, as this will help someone answer your question.

Comment: I did some quick googling and I think I've got what you're asking for. I put the sample at the end of my post. (I'm VERY new to R, so everything is a struggle right now)

Comment: The `OTIF` column in the sample data you provided are all zeros. Can you provide a dataset where you can at least reproduce the difference you seen in those plots?

Comment: I've updated the information to show non-zero values. I also added an edit to clarify that I do expect some zeros in the earlier years, but none after. Thanks for pointing this out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your "small" data subset, try this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(lubridate)
library(R.utils)

tidyr::separate(small, col = "YearMonth", into = c("Month", "Year")) %>%
  mutate(Month = R.utils::capitalize(tolower(Month))) %>%
  mutate(Day = "1") %>%
  select(Year, Month, Day, everything()) %>%
  unite(col = "Date", Year, Month, Day, sep = "-") %>%
  mutate(Date = lubridate::ymd(Date)) -> small2

timeseries <- ts(small2$OTIF, start = c(2007, 10), end = c(2008, 8), frequency = 12)
plot(timeseries)
```

[image]

Comment: That is perfect! I altered it to use a dataset that has the years I'm looking at and it worked perfectly. It looks like it put my date in a YYYY-MM-DD format, correct? What does this last portion do? "mutate(Date = lubridate::ymd(Date)) -> small2"

Comment: Yes, that is correct. It is usually easier to work with a "complete" date format with days added. So for monthly data, just add the first day of the month. The last part changes the "Date" column from type "character" to type "Date", and then lastly it is saved as "small2", with a reversed assignment operator. The `lubridate::ymd()` is just to show that the `ymd()` function comes from the lubridate package.

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm allowed to ask followup questions, but do you know how I would replace the YearMonth variable in the dataset with "small2"? I'm running regression analysis and want to utilize this new variable.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean here. In the code I have provided, the YearMonth variable is replaced by a variable called Date.

Comment: Oh! I just realized it created a tibble. I ran the re-ran the regression as:  
     model27<- lm(OTIF~N + TR_Value_LineItems+ Date, data=small2)

Comment: If you find my comments helpful, you can help me by marking my answer as useful in addition to accepting the answer by clicking the grey upward triangle. Thanks!

Comment: Done and done! It won't display because I'm too new, but I clicked it. Thanks again!